# Does miracle flatness always fail for a non-regular base?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, flatness, hyperkaehler

In [1], Huybrechts and Mauri argue that a holomorphic Lagrangian fibration $f: X \to B$ with smooth base $B$ is flat. This is an application of so called miracle flatness [2, Thm 23.1], because Lagrangian fibrations have equidimensional fibers. Then they write

> *Remark 1.18.* Note that the conclusion that $f$ is flat really needs the base to be smooth. In fact, by miracle flatness, $f$ is flat if and only if $B$ is smooth.

I see that smoothness of $B$ is needed to apply miracle flatness, but I don't see the converse. Why does flatness necessarily fail if $B$ is not smooth?

[1] Huybrechts, Mauri, [*Lagrangian fibrations*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00032-022-00349-y), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.10193), 2022

[2] Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, 1986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in *Theorem 23.7* from Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*:

> *Theorem 23.7.* Let $(A, \mathfrak m, k)$ and $(B, \mathfrak n, k')$ be local Noetherian local rings, and $A \to B$ a local homomorphism [...]. We assume that $B$ is flat over $A$. (i) If $B$ is regular then so is $A$.

As $X$ is always assumed to be smooth, the flatness of $f$ will imply the smoothness of the base $B$.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but does this imply that the regularity satisfies fpqc descent for Noetherian ring (I have not heard results of this kind before)? Namely, given a faithfully flat map $R\to S$ of Noetherian rings. If $S$ is regular, then so is $R$.

Comment: @Z.M Good point, I think you are correct. Though I'm not too experienced with descent.